# passing a NSManagedObject to an UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, ios5

If I pass a NSManagedObject to a UIViewController, the NSManagedObject becomes null. The only way around it that I can see is to use a fetch request in each view controller i want to pass the managed object to (there are several) but this seems extremely clumsy and prone to error.

The way I'm passing the managed object is just to say:

```
viewController.subclassedManagedObject = self.subclassedManagedObject;
```

it's valid in self but in viewController it's null. I don't understand why. any insight would be much appreciated!

Many thanks

Edit:

to add a bit more detail and clarity: i have a strong subclassed managedObject property called booking in viewController.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Booking *booking;
```

This is also the viewController where I set up UIManagedDocument and such. This all works fine. I want to pass this managedObject to an instance of TableViewController which I do like this:

```
Booking *booking = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Booking" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];


    [self.bookingDatabase saveToURL:self.bookingDatabase.fileURL
            forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForOverwriting
           completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
               if (!success) 
               {
                NSLog(@"didn't work");
               }}];

    TableViewController *tableViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    tableViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    tableViewController.booking = self.booking; 
    tableViewController.bookingDatabase = self.bookingDatabase;
```

The property booking in TableViewController i've tried being both weak and strong and neither work. At the moment it's like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) Booking *booking;
```

Many thanks again

Comment: Can you post more of your code? How are you presenting this view controller? Is the property set to retain?

Comment: Thanks for having a look. Yes i've posted some more in my original post.

Answer (score 6):

You're passing self.booking to tableViewController but what you're creating looks like a new local variable:

```
Booking *booking = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Booking" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

When it should be

```
self.booking = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Booking" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

If that doesn't fix it you could try setting your NSManagedObjectContext to retain new objects, it's possible that when you transition to the new tableViewController the autoreleased NSManagedObject goes away:

```
[managedObjectContext setRetainsRegisteredObjects:YES];
```

Comment: You're welcome! You should mark this answer as accepted if you don't need any more answers.

Answer (score 2):

Have you verified that `tableViewController` is not nil?

your `@property` should definitely be strong as the view controller is taking ownership of the entity.  A `weak` reference will definitely nil out.

Likewise I would also put a breakpoint in the debugger and **confirm** that `[self booking]` does indeed point to a valid object *at that point in the code*.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is the proper way and i dont have any documentation to quote.  but i believe you should create a singleton, on open load your values from you managed object into the singleton and use that in your uiviewcontrollers.

then on close save the singleton to your managed object

Comment: Never use singletons.  They are the fastest way to code yourself into an unmaintainable corner.

Comment: um, that is not true, all i have read said singletons are fine and if you do them right you can even make them thread safe.   the argument about singletons are all based around thread safety not "unmaintainable corner"  i find it quite insulting that you not only mark me down one but use vague terms for your reasonings

Comment: Singletons are evil, especially on a mobile device.  They do not allow for you to tear them down, they do not allow for proper memory management, they cause tight coupling throughout the code base.  They should NOT be used.  The arguments are not only about thread safety but about coupling and memory management.

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra I don't think a singleton is the solution to this problem, if anything it is just a strategy, it does not address the OPs problem. I do however disagree with your blanket statement, there are some very good use cases for singletons in software development. It is all a matter of personal preference though, no specific design pattern is ever required.

Comment: not to mention some core classes are singletons.  "Several Cocoa framework classes are singletons. They include NSFileManager, NSWorkspace, and, in UIKit, UIApplication and UIAccelerometer." http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Singleton.html

Comment: the app delegate is simliar to a singleton in the respect that it "do not allow you to tear them down"  and yet every ios app has them

Comment: @owengerig just because the OS uses some singletons (and less of them are actually singletons then you might think) does not mean an app on iOS should use them.  In iOS, your application should not use a singleton.  Don't confuse the frameworks from iOS and your application, they are not in the same category.

Comment: @ChrisWagner To avoid blanket statements would require another book :) Far easier to say "Don't do this" than to say "Don't do this unless you *really* know what you are doing, but then in that case you would not need my advice because you know what you are doing already and therefore can safely ignore me".  The first statement is easier for modern ADD to consume.

Comment: either way this is not the place for that discussion, i would delete this post as it has turned into an argument about singletons however my answer would work and so i wont.  in the end people always need to read up and make their own discussions.  either way i would assume the "never use singletons" argument comes up anytime that word is used.

Comment: @owengerig Your solution does not work which is why I marked it down.

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra I would be interested in discussing further on the topic. You are clearly very knowledgeable in iOS and it's always great to get insight from someone like you. I have a tendency to fall back on singletons for simplicity sake.

Comment: @ChrisWagner Yeah I should probably do a post on CIMGF about them, especially as they relate to Core Data.  I will add it to the list.  Otherwise if you want to contact me directly you are welcome.

Comment: well lets meet up in the iphone/ipad chat room?  the one thing i dont get on the argument for this specific case is this "use a fetch request in each view controller."  by this i think we can assume there are quite a few view controllers and that they all need access to the object.  so if there are a large number of accessors and that accessing needs to be done for the length of the program why not use a singleton.